# webpack package the ts file used the exist sourcemap

Tags: typescript, webpack, source-maps, babel-loader, ts-loader

I have a program like this:
First , I have a list of **typescript files**.Then I have a compiler compile the **ts file to *.obf.ts**(this is a special typescript file) and generate the **sourcemap**.

After this, Webpack will take the after compile steps **(ts-loader, babel-loader)**.
But the sourcemap just convert the file to the ***.obf.ts** file ,not the **original ts file**.

I already used the source-map-loader plugin, but the ts-loader seems don't accept the input sourcemap.

So how can I convert back to the original ts file?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I can't provide the compiler(transform the ts code to the obf.ts code) for some reasons.But the obf.ts code is still the typescript code and the other tools are standard tool.